# Creating dynamic named ranges in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create ~200 dynamic (want ability to alter number of data points) named ranges to use in charts.

I have the names of the ranges and the formulas set up in a worksheet as follows:

```
Name    Range
Range1  Com!OFFSET($B$13,COUNTA(A:A)-Csummary!$U$1,0,Csummary!$U$1,1)
Range2  Com!OFFSET($C$13,COUNTA(A:A)-Csummary!$U$1,0,Csummary!$U$1,1)
Range3  Com!OFFSET($D$13,COUNTA(A:A)-Csummary!$U$1,0,Csummary!$U$1,1)
Range4  Com!OFFSET($E$13,COUNTA(A:A)-Csummary!$U$1,0,Csummary!$U$1,1)
Range5  Com!OFFSET($F$13,COUNTA(A:A)-Csummary!$U$1,0,Csummary!$U$1,1)
```

This code below worked for creating conventional named ranges, but does not seem to work with the dynamic variety.

```
Sub Range()
For x = 1 To 20
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Cells(x + 1, 1).Value, RefersTo:="=" & Cells(x + 1, 2).Value

Next x

End Sub
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Com!OFFSET(` does not look correct to me.  You sure it should not be: `OFFSET(Com!$B$13,COUNTA(Com!A:A)...`?

Comment: So if You go to the named range manager in Excel and put that formula, does it work?  First make sure the formula works manually before trying to do it programmatically.

Comment: Record a macro while creating one of those ranges.  That will give you the changes you need to make to your current loop code.  For example replace `RefersTo` with `RefersToR1C1`

Comment: This works in the named range manager:

=OFFSET(com!$B$13,COUNTA(com!$A:$A)-Csummary!$U$1,0,Csummary!$U$1,1)

Was hoping to avoid doing this 200x

Comment: now that you have a working formula you can try your code again with the fixed formulas.

Comment: For some reason that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: *What exactly* didn't work ? You can update your question to add what you tried, and what error you got when you tried it.